# ASP controls "shifting" in C# web app

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a 2.0 framework C# web application.  Recently it was brought to my attention that when an event occurs (button submits in particular) on the page and then the other ASP controls are moused over (textboxes, radio buttons, regular buttons) they appear to shift down, all the while you can see the control in its original position underneath (This gives the effect of having duplicate controls, one overlapping the other).  When the page is refreshed the issue goes away until another event takes place.

To give some background, the users only experience this in IE.  Of all the people I had test this, it only happens on a very small number of computers.  One last thing to add is that I am incorporating JQuery rounded corners in the divs above the controls that seem to "break".

Has anyone seen this issue before, and if so, how was it fixed?  A little bit of insight would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your jQuery code is cloning the HTML elements.  If you turn off your jQuery to round the corners, does the problem still occur?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't heard of this particular bug before, but it may be one that's fixed using the [IE Zoom fix](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/haslayout.html), which fixes bugs caused by IE6's strange float model.